# Background-size transition to another page

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I want to make a background-image effect which makes smooth background transition from one page to another like on this page http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/ when you press on one of the images it makes it bigger and transitions nicely to the next page.

Html below:

index page:

```
<a href="another_page.html">Portfolio
 <div class="test"></div>
</a>
```

another page:

```
<div class="test1"></div>
```

css below:

```
.test{
background-image: url("test.jpeg");
height: 100vh;
background-position: 70% center;
width: 700px;
background-size: auto 100%;
transform: matrix(0.8, 0, 0, 0.8, -329.75, 0);

}

.test1{
background-image: url("test.jpeg");
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
transition: background-size 10s ease-in;
background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

I'm new to the transitions and key frames and not very experienced developer so not sure what to use here, maybe it needs jquery not sure. Anyone's help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the website you shared and with your question and I can only provide you with the technologies the site is using so you can look at it and use on your project as well. Hope it helps;

So, the site makes use of 2 Javascript frameworks;

1. TweenMax found here https://greensock.com/tweenmax
2. Hammer found here http://hammerjs.github.io/

I think you may find Hammer more important as that produces the effects you are looking for. Do check them both out and let me know.